# Django prepopulated_fields is adding 'cfakepath' to fields when targeting ImageField

Tags: django, django-admin

I have heard it might not be made for this, but I'd really like to have it just take the file's name for the slug and title.

```
class RandomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {
        'slug': ('image',),
        'title': ('image',)
    }
```

where 'image' is an ImageField...

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="random_uploads")
```

If the files name is 'abc_123.jpg', I get 'cfakepathabc_123jpg'. I'd like to get 'abc_123jpg' or 'abc_123'.

Any tips for me? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot be done trivially, without modifying prepopulated_fields_js.html, since it just looks for the value of the dependent fields.

In otherwords, you can't just do it by changing something in the ModelAdmin.  You'd have to override prepopulated_fields_js.html and make some specific exceptions.

Comment: Thanks! I'll leave it for now.. maybe I'll explore later.